# @Query MongoDb с динамическими параметрами Spring

Tags: java, mongodb

Необходимо выбрать записи из MongoDB, где dataEdit >= параметра, передаваемого пользователем в запросе.
Делаю следующим образом:

```
public interface OffersRepository extends MongoRepository<Offers, String> {

    @Query("{ 'dateEdit' : { $eq: ?0, $gt: ?0 } }")
    List<Offers> findBydateEdit(String dateEdit);
    Offers findBy_id(String _id);

}
```

И потом вызываю:

```
@Autowired
private OffersRepository offersRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/{time}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Offers> getOffersBydateEdit(@PathVariable ("time") String time) throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = null;
    date = format.parse(time);
    return offersRepository.findBydateEdit(format.format(date));

}
```

Возвращает следующим результат: []

Если не использовать данный метод, а просто отфильтровать самому, то результат будет совершенно другой, он вернет подходящие мне записи. 
Код следующий:

```
@Autowired
private OffersRepository offersRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/{time}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ArrayList<Offers> getOffersBydateEdit(@PathVariable ("time") String time) throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = null;
    date = format.parse(time);
    format.format(date);

    List<Offers> ret = offersRepository.findAll();
    ArrayList<Offers> ret1 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Offers offer : ret) {
        String s = offer.getDateEdit();
        Date data = format.parse(s);
        if (data.after(date) || data.equals(date)) {
            ret1.add(offer);
        }
    }

    return ret1;
}
```

Что я делаю не так при использовании @Query?
Информацию по Query брал отсюда: https://www.baeldung.com/queries-in-spring-data-mongodb
Также сделал проверку запроса в [Robo3T](https://robomongo.org/) и подсчитал количество подходящих мне записей:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте оператор gte вместо eq и gt. А еще советую включить дебаг логгинг для монго. По логам вы сможете понять какое квери делает ваше приложение в базу.

Comment: подстановка gte помогла